# How can I remove sitemesh exclude config dynamicly in filter?

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker, sitemesh

I hava an sitemesh decorator.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/decorators">
<excludes>
    <pattern>/merchant/brand/*</pattern>
    <pattern>/merchant/spu</pattern>
</excludes>

<decorator name="centralized">
    <pattern>/*</pattern>
</decorator>
```

And I use a filter to control the sitemesh decorate dynamicly. How can i know the excludes patterns in decorator.xml use API.

```
public class NewMenuFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
   String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
   //todo:if new contextPath,remove the sitemesh exclude config 
   request.setAttribute("Header_HeadType", "XXX");
   //else 
   request.setAttribute("Header_HeadType", "YYY");
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

}

How can I remove sitemesh exclude config dynamicly in filter,like remove `<pattern>/merchant/spu</pattern>` in `todo:if new contextPath,remove the sitemesh exclude config` use API.